# How to stack filters if parameters exist or not?

Tags: django, django-models

If I have something such as this:

```
    tasks = Task.objects.filter( 
        Q(datetime__contains=date)
        & Q(user=uid) if uid!=0 else
        & Q(member=mid) if mid!=0 else
        & Q(job=jid) if jid!=0 else
    )
```

It will stack/mix the filters dependent on what function parameters are passed, but obviously that doesn't work, what is the best way to continue?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain calls to `filter` within if statements to "stack" conditional filters

```py
tasks = Task.objects.filter( 
    datetime__contains=date
)
if uid != 0:
    tasks = tasks.filter(user=uid)
if mid != 0:
    tasks = tasks.filter(member=mid)
if jid != 0:
    tasks = tasks.filter(job=jid)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be dictionary unpacking:

```
data = {'user': uid, 'member': mid, 'job': jid}

tasks = Task.objects.filter(
    **{ k: v for k, v in data.items() if v != 0 },
    datetime__contains=date
)
```